# Outlook Desktop App ignores margin 0 and padding 0

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, email-client

I am making a e-mail with HTML and CSS. On most of the e-mail clients it works fine but the Outlook Desktop App (I use Windows) ignores the `margin: 0` and `padding: 0`. I have declared it this way with CSS:

```
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

And I can't find the solution for this.

Comment: There isn't a solution. Outlook's HTML email rendering support is based on Word's, which hasn't really changed much since 2007, which doesn't support many (any?) features added to CSS since the early-2000s. That's why HTML email today will have a header link for Outlook users (hidden from everyone else with conditional-comments) to a publicly-hosted web-page version of the e-mail.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to remove margin and padding from?

Comment: @Nathan I wan't to remove the `margin` from everything, unless I specificly give an element `margin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all e-mail clients accept all forms of CSS selectors. Have a look at this [CSS Support Guide for Email Clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/selectors/universal/) to check which clients accept which CSS selectors.

As an alternative, you could add `padding` to an inline element (for example, the `body` tag):

```html
<body style="padding: 0;">
</body>
```

However, Outlook Desktop does not accept `margin`, unfortunately. Here is [a list of all the CSS](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/email-client/outlook-2007-16/) that Outlook does not accept.

Comment: What should I use as alternative?

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule assume email clients only look at inline styling. Style tags in the header will be ignored.

This is one of the aspects that makes crafting consistent HTML emails particularly tedious. The other bad one being the need to nest tables to make them mobile responsive.

Comment: I can't get it to work :( . Can you please give me an example of how you mean to do it?